# Lined Server - Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "IBMDADB2.DB2COPY2" for linked server "MYDB2"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, db2, linked-server, db2-luw

I would like to create Linked Server from SQL Server 2016 on Windows to Db2 v11.5.7 on Linux/x86.

I created linked Server using *Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2* and it works fine.

Now I would like to create Lined Server using **IBM Db2 provider** and compare performances, features etc. But I got into a problem. See bellow.

1. I turned on **Allow inprocess** setting at Providers.

[image]

2. Created new linked server:

[image]

3. Set security:

[image]

4. Default settings

[image]

5. When I click on OK button I get error: *The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?*
   And detailed error: *Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "IBMDADB2.DB2COPY2" for linked server "MYDB2". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)*

[image]

6. Then I added some permissions following article:
   https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/troubleshooting-8220-cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db/ba-p/316675
7. Drop linked server and re-created it, but the same error.
8. I opened Db2 client (db2cmd) and tested connection to data source, userid and password provided in step 3 and connection works fine.

I am trying to solve this problem for couple of days. I have searched the web and can't figure it out what is wrong. Any idea what to test or how to debug this problem?

**Additional info:**

a) IBM instructions how to create Lined Server:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-create-linked-server-ibm-db2-ole-db-provider

b) Video how to create Linked server using IBM Db2 provider:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2V6daHYuuZ4&t=812s